# Basepage not showing

Tags: database

I recently installed civicrm on a wordpress install. I followed the installed and went through the installation. I thought I would see a log in page for civicrm on the /civicrm link. I am seeing a page that outlines that it is coming from civicrm, but no content. How do I see a way for users to log in and use the database?

Answer (score 1):

User management is handled thru the CMS so the login will be at example.org/login if you've not altered the login URL. Users will need at minimum the `access CiviCRM backend and API` permission to see CiviCRM on the Wordpress admin menu on the left.

[image]

The base page by default is "/civicrm" but this is for natively displaying contribution/event pages and other dynamic content from CiviCRM.